# R: add sheet to an existing excel workbook

Tags: r, xlsx

In my script, I need to create an excel workbook with many sheets, where the first 2 sheets are by default, read from another workbook and incorporated into the exported excel.

Im using the `xlsx` package to format the export excel. However, I could not find any function in the `xlsx` package, that could read a sheet from an excel, and add it to another one.

Here is my code to read the first excel:

```
template_wb <- loadWorkbook(file = 'template.xlsx')
sheets <- getSheets(wb)  
sheet1 <- sheets[[1]]
sheet2 <- sheets[[2]]
```

In the second part of the code, i create another workbook, which contains multiple sheets, from which, `sheet1` and `sheet2`, should be one of.

```
 wb<-createWorkbook(type="xlsx")
 as_sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "AS")
 dc_sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "DC")
 ro_sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "RO")

 ### add content to worksheets
 # the suggested code should go there

### save workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, 'out.xlsx')
```

I would like to add the content of `sheet1` to `dc_sheet` and the content of `sheet2` to `ro_sheet` before adding more data into `as_sheet` and then saving the workbook.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure a simple assignment statement will do the trick:

```
template_wb <- loadWorkbook(file = 'template.xlsx')
sheets <- getSheets(template_wb)  
sheet1 <- sheets[[1]]
sheet2 <- sheets[[2]]
wb<-createWorkbook(type="xlsx")
as_sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "AS")
dc_sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "DC")
ro_sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "RO")
dc_sheet<-sheet1
ro_sheet<-sheet2
# Your code here
saveWorkbook(wb, 'out.xlsx')
```

I tried it out and it worked fine

Comment: i tried this, and it didnt work. The sheets are empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with a copy, and save it as a new file.

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(file)  
# Rename the sheets
wb$setSheetName(0L, "AS")
wb$setSheetName(1L, "DC")
# Delete the aditional sheets
sheets <- getSheets(wb)  
lapply(names(sheets)[-(1:2)], function(x) removeSheet(wb, sheetName = x))
# Assign the sheets to the objects of R
sheets <- getSheets(wb)  
as_sheet <- sheets[[1]]
dc_sheet <- sheets[[2]]
# Create the new sheet
ro_sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "RO")
# save workbook
saveWorkbook(wb, 'out.xlsx')
```

Comment: the assignment simply did not work. did it work for you?